# Changing host and vhost.conf file (lion) broke localhost

Tags: permissions, apache2, osx-lion, localhost, vhosts

I am using OSX local web server and today I needed to set up a virtual host. After doing so, accessing localhost in a browser hangs. 127.0.0.1 says permission denied. Even after I reverted the changed to the files I made under etc/. What's weird is when I check my web sharing, it says the web server can be accessed via { someone-else's-computer.local/~my comp name }. That someone else is someone who is on the same router as me. When I disconnect my wifi, it says it can be accessed via my computer name. I don't know what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out something about what I did while editing it the first time or saving it out using TextMate screwed up the file. I backed up hosts file, duplicated hosts-original, renamed it hosts, and the selected all and pasted the contact back in. So basically the content didn't change, but instead I saved it out of text wrangler this time and magic! It worked. Computers are so annoying sometimes.